# Error during multistage Docker build: sh: next: not found

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a NextJS project with the following lines in my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
  },
```

All three scripts run without any hiccups from my command line. Now I’m trying to dockerize my application. My definitions are in a `Dockerfile.prod`:

```
# Final stage
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Install Node base image with Alpine Ubuntu
FROM node:20.11-alpine AS builder
# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app
# Install pnpm globally in the builder stage
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN npm install -g pnpm
# Copy package.json and pnpm-lock.yaml
COPY pnpm-lock.yaml package.json ./
# Install dependencies using pnpm
RUN pnpm install
# Copy the rest of the files to the working directory
COPY . .
# Generate Prisma Client
RUN npx prisma db push
RUN npx prisma generate
RUN pnpm build

# Runner stage
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Install Node base image with Alpine Ubuntu
FROM node:20.11-alpine AS runner
# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app
# Install pnpm globally in the builder stage
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN npm install -g pnpm
# Copy only the necessary files from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js /app/.next /app/public /app/node_modules ./
# Expose port 3000 from the container
EXPOSE 3001
# Start the Next.js server
CMD ["pnpm", "start"]
```

Besides, I also have a `docker-compose.yaml` that looks like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  poco-production:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    container_name: poco-web-prod
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    env_file:
      - .env
```

Now when I build this image using `docker-compose up --build`, I get the following error:

> Attaching to poco-web-prod
> poco-web-prod  |
> poco-web-prod  | > poco@0.1.0 start /app
> poco-web-prod  | > next start
> poco-web-prod  |
> poco-web-prod  | sh: next: not found
> poco-web-prod  |  ELIFECYCLE  Command failed.

What am I missing here? ChatGPT says this:

> The error message you’re encountering—`sh: next: not found`—indicates that the `next` command is not being found within your container.

But that can’t be true because this error only comes at `next start` while `next build` runs just fine. I am also copying my `node_modules` from the `build` stage into the `runner` stage. What else could be missing?

**UPDATE**

As suggested by Ahmed Abdelbaset in his answer below, I updated my Dockerfile to this:

```
# Install Node base image with Alpine Ubuntu
FROM node:20.11-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app
# Copy dependency lists
COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
# Enable corepack for pnpm
RUN corepack enable pnpm
# Install dependencies using pnpm
RUN pnpm i --frozen-lockfile



# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
# Generate Prisma Client
RUN npx prisma db push
RUN npx prisma generate
# Enable corepack for pnpm and install dependencies
RUN corepack enable pnpm && pnpm build


# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Disable NextJS telemetry during runtime
ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

# server.js is created by next build from the standalone output
# https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

And added `output: "standalone"` to my `next.config.js` as follows:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    config.resolve.alias.canvas = false
    config.resolve.alias.encoding = false
    return config
  },
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "lh3.googleusercontent.com",
        pathname: "**",
      },
    ],
  },
  output: "standalone",
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

This is now throwing a different error:

> Cannot find module '/app/server.js'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error message you’re encountering—sh: next: not found—indicates that the next command is not being found within your container.

That's true, before the `pnpm build` (`next build`) you have `pnpm install` which generates `node_modules`. But before `pnpm start` (`next start`), You don't have `node_modules`.

```
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js /app/.next /app/public /app/node_modules ./
```

The previous line will copy the contents of the sources not the directories themselves. The output will not be:

```
- next.config.js
- .next/
  - static
  - server
  - ...
- public
  - ...
- node_modules
  - .pnpm
  - next
  - ...
```

But it will be

```
- next.config.js
- static
- server
- .pnpm
- ...
```

so, there is no `node_modules`.

Next.js provides a `standalone` output the collect all necessary files to run output in Docker in one place. To enable, configure `next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  output: "standalone",
}
```

After running `next build`, you'll have `.next/standalone` dir that is stand alone in itself - no need to any other directory.

```
# Runner stage
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Install Node base image with Alpine Ubuntu
FROM node:20.11-alpine AS runner
# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy only the necessary files from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/static ./static

# Expose port 3001 from the container
EXPOSE 3001
# Start the Next.js server
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

During running the server, Next.js will write/read `.next` this might conflict with the docker permissions. If that happened you will need

```
# Runner stage
# --------------------------------------------------------
# Install Node base image with Alpine Ubuntu
FROM node:20.11-alpine AS runner
# Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app


RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Copy only the necessary files from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./static

USER nextjs

# Expose port 3001 from the container
EXPOSE 3001
# Start the Next.js server
CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

#### Further Reading

- standalone output: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output
- with-docker example: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker

Comment: This fails with error: Cannot find module '/app/server.js'

Comment: Have you updated next.config `output: "standalone"`

Comment: Yes, please see my updates to the question. I did all you suggested.

Comment: I had a typo in my answer at copying static dir `COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./static` I corrected it now. this correction will not solve the server.js issue. If you have the Docker Desktop installed can you look for the files generated? If you can [provide a reproduction](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I'll look into it.

Comment: I am unable to inspect the files in Docker desktop likely because the build exists immediately upon error. I have a repo that I could share on Github but since it doesn’t have the .env file (some env values necessary for prisma setup), I don’t know if you’ll be able to reproduce it. Anyway, here it is: https://github.com/schandillia/poco/tree/auth

Comment: Also, just noticed that before the error about missing `server.js`, there’s another error about this: `Error: Cannot find module '/app/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next'`. Not sure if this is any help?

Comment: I look at your repo, after swapping the 20th line and 21th line it worked. Move `COPY . .` before `COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules`